# Can SVN pull request same as GIT?

Tags: svn

I am new to SVN but knew GIT. I read this question : 
[How to send pull request on Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235379/how-to-send-pull-request-on-git)

A question, can SVN pull request same as GIT ?

Comment: You can read the SVNBook to get it explained: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.html

Answer (score 36):

A pull request in Git is typically used to ask someone, using his own repo, to pull changes from another repo (which is a clone of the original repo).

SVN only uses one repo for everybody, so the closest matches to a pull request would be:

- you developed a feature in a branch, and ask the trunk maintainer to reintegrate your branch into the trunk
- you developed a feature in your own working copy of the trunk, and send a patch file to the trunk maintainer in order to commit the changes into the trunk.

Answer (score 8):

This can be done in SVN, but it is more complex and requires a secondary branch.   When development is complete in your branch:

1. Create a merge (pull) branch from the trunk and check that out.
2. Merge you development check-out branch into the "pull" branch.
3. Run test threads and do compares to verify the merge.
4. Integrate with the trunk.

Note 1: Depending on the size of your software baseline this can be very time consuming.
Note 2: Warning; If you attempt to merge the trunk with (pull updates into) your original development branch directly, you will create a paradox that reverses the changes you want to integrate.  This can be very difficult to recover from.

Comment: Note 2: You can avoid that if you first synchronize tunk changes to the branch.

Comment: What's the advantage doing this in a different branch? You can do the same on the feature branch.