# Merge issues on large Git/TeamCity project with 4 releases

Tags: git, merge

My teammates and myself work for a software vendor, building a large piece of software for a client. Dozens of devs, uses Git for source control. We have 4 releases:

- 0.9: in production
- 0.9.1: being tested at the client
- 1.0: being tested by us (the software vendor)
- 1.1: being built

Our current work practice is that when you for example fix a bug in for example 0.9.1,

- you pull the latest 0.9.1, then push your fix to 0.9.1
- switch to 1.0, pull latest 1.0, merge 0.9.1, push to 1.0
- switch to 1.1, pull latest 1.1, merge 1.0, push to 1.1

Problem is that with dozens of devs, often multiple people are trying to push their fixes at the same time. As a result, often people are doing the same merge, merging each others' changes. For example:

- dev1 pushes fix1 to 0.9.1, pulls 1.0 and starts merging
- While dev1 is merging to 1.0, dev2 pushes fix2 to 0.9.1, pulls 1.0 and starts merging their own fix2, but also fix1
- Plus merging needs to be done to 1.1 as well.

I suspect that because of all this pain, people tend to do lots of commits on their local machines (not backed up) and then do large merges say once a day or once every couple of days - so other devs work against outdated code.

I guess this problem happens on other large Git based projects too. Would like to hear from people who've worked on such project on how they dealt with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> While dev1 is merging to 1.0, dev2 pushes fix2 to 0.9.1, pulls 1.0 and starts merging their own fix2, but also fix1

If dev2 was not up to date at the time of his push, the remote will reject it. You have to be up to date before you can push, unless they are `git push -f`, which is another issue altogether.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you probably need to "partition" your project into more files. Modulate more, user more [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). This is by large a very difficult job to do and nearly impossible in some cases.

Then, you got basically 2 options, depending on the project size.

- **For bigger projects**: Use [**pull requests**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235379/how-to-send-pull-request-on-git).

  I got no experience here, but you should do your own research if you're going with [Linus or GitHub](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&ved=0CGoQFjAG&url=http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/2012/05/torvalds_github/&ei=H6mcUpiEBdTqkQfQsIHQDg&usg=AFQjCNG_iyNw6OXE80u2zRjVmfRuTI-Tew&sig2=n9rqGolJplqQcHZadLE-nA&bvm=bv.57155469,d.eW0) on this one. In either case, that's what the biggest projects do, such as [jquery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pulls).

  In this scenario, most devs should not be able to push anymore and there still will be the *pain* of synchronizing work - but this can be potentially reduced to zero if you divide the project in enough files so each dev work in one at a time. Re-enforcing the first step, this doesn't mean simply dividing files, but it means making each file as independent as it can be, so you can apply [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing).
- **For smaller ones**: Coordinate. [**Branch**`*`](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Communicate.

  If the team is small, branching and emailing should be enough. Get in touch to decide who'll do what first. By branching you don't have to merge all the time. Then you get in touch again if there is a big conflict in which merge is needed. This is also not really easy to begin, but it works.

  `*` **Beware** if you decide to follow nvie's advice. There is at least [one big **flaw**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850369/why-does-git-use-fast-forward-merging-by-default) on that model.