# Include only specific commits in a pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Let's say I have cloned repository, created new branch "Topic1", made changes, commited them and then pushed them to a remote repo `git push origin Topic1`. After that I made a pull request into master branch.

Then on my local repository I checkout from branch "Topic1" to branch "Topic2", made some changes there, commited and again pushed this new branch to remote. And again made a pull request into master. I want to mention that in the meantime no changes were made to master branch, so I didn't need to sync my local repo with upstream.

And here's the problem: when I go to pull request page of "Topic2" all the commits of "Topic1" are presented there. So, my question - how can I get in 2nd pull request commits related only to "Topic2" branch?

Comment: Related: Some good details on [how the pull requests are different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6235379/465053) in Git (the software) and GitHub (the web service)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "pull request" a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027850/how-to-pull-request-a-specific-commit)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. Create a new branch based on `upstream/master`
2. [cherry-pick](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) the relevant commits from your branch *Topic2* (into the new branch)
3. Create a pull request from this new branch.

Comment: The problem is that I need all the changes made in Topic1 branch to be in Topic2, which not currently yet in master branch. But I don't want them to be displayed in pull request related to Topic2 branch.

Comment: Thats not possible. Pull requests include all changes in comparison to the target branch. But you could have 3 branches: one as your "working branch" with merged commits from Topic1 and Topic2 and the two other branches just for the pull requests.