# Creating a PR from a specific commit

Tags: git, github

I want to create a PR with a single commit, so I checkout a new branch with commmit SHA,

```
git checkout -b new-branch 8517c80183607461ea
```

How do I create a PR from here?

Comment: Did you try `git push origin new-branch`? You just have to create a PR from within `new-branch` afterwards.

Answer (score 10):

Because of the way Git branches work, it's not enough to make a branch off a single commit. You might drag in more commits.

For example, let's say your repository looks like this.

```
A - B - C [master]
         \
          D - E - F [feature]
```

`master` and `feature` are just labels pointing to a commit. `master` points at commit C. `feature` points at commit F.

Git commits do not live in isolation. They take their whole history with them. F cannot exist without E, D, C, B, and A. If you push `feature` then F will bring E and D along with it (assuming C is already pushed).

Let's say you want to send a PR of only E. So you make a branch at E.

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch E

A - B - C [master]
         \
          D - E [new-branch]
               \
                F [feature]
```

All that's done is created a label called `new-branch` pointing to commit E. The structure of the commits remains the same. If you then push `new-branch` it will drag D along with it. This is why sometimes when you think you're pushing only a few commits the PR contains many more commits.

---

In order to really push just one commit, you need to detach it from its history. You can do this with a [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). This basically takes the commit, turns it into a patch, and patches it somewhere else.

Going back to your original repository...

```
A - B - C [master]
         \
          D - E - F [feature]
```

You'd make a new branch off `master`.

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch master

          [new-branch]
A - B - C [master]
         \
          D - E - F [feature]
```

(Note that nothing changed except a new branch label was made pointing at C.)

Then cherry pick E. This will copy E as a new commit on top of C. There may be conflicts, resolve them as normal.

```
$ git cherry-pick E

          E1 [new-branch]
         / 
A - B - C [master]
         \
          D - E - F [feature]
```

Now you can push `new-branch` and only E1 will be in the PR.

Answer (score 2):

You need to push `new-branch` to Github, and then open a pull request. This will include all commits reachable from `8517c80183607461ea` but not already in the history of `master`.

If you want to include **only** `8517c80183607461ea`, then you need to rebase `new-branch` onto master using `git rebase -i master`, and delete all the lines except the one mentioning `8517c80183607461ea`. After the rebase, your branch `new-branch` will contain the rebased `8517c80183607461ea` with its new commit ID, directly on top of master, and you can push your branch/issue a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a little bit of trouble using [Schwern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964277/6332373) since I was making the error of being on master of a forked project while making commits ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57126783/6332373) I'm calling it a rookie mistake).

Following Schwern's graphs let's say I've forked a project at `C` and proceeded on master with the other commits. Here I am adding an asterisk to signal that new changes are happening on the fork:

```bash
A - B - C - D* - E* - F* [master]
```

If you want to cherry-pick only some of the commits (say `D` and `E`) what you should **not** do is:

```bash
git checkout -b new-branch upstream/master
git cherry-pick <hash of commit D>
git cherry-pick <hash of commit E>
git push -u origin new-branch
```

In this case, you're trying to branch out the master at `F*` and cherry picking the previous commits will get you the warning

> "The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution."

since you're adding the same old commits on the new branch.

What you should do instead is:

```bash
git checkout -b new-branch <hash of commit E>
git push -u origin new-branch

A - B - C - D* - E* - F* - G* [master]
                  \
              D* - E* [new-branch]
```

After this, you're ready to make a pull request with only the selected commits.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the specific file direct on github. Github will do a patch branch automatic and so you can PR just a single file out of your branch.