# How to pull specific commit from remote repo

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I have 2 repos in my local project:

```
1. remote        # this is my working area, where I want to push a commit from side_repo
2. side_repo     # this is remote repo, where I want to pull the commit from
```

I read the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027850/how-to-pull-request-a-specific-commit), and try to repeat the steps:

```
git remote add side_repo <url_of_side_repo>   # add remote repo
git fetch --all                               # fetch all chanches from remote and side_repo
git checkout -b backport side_repo/master     # create new branch based on master of side_repo
git cherry-pick <hash_of_commit_in_side_repo> # pull the commit from side_repo/master
```

After that I got this message:

```
Auto-merging arch/riscv/include/asm/pgtable.h
warning: inexact rename detection was skipped due to too many files.
warning: you may want to set your merge.renamelimit variable to at least 2193 and retry the command.
On branch backport
Your branch is up to date with 'side_repo/master'.

You are currently cherry-picking commit cba43c31f14b.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git cherry-pick --continue")
  (use "git cherry-pick --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

Otherwise, please use 'git cherry-pick --skip'
```

I checked if I got chanches, I need. And it is ok: now file *arch/riscv/include/asm/pgtable.h* is correct.

BUT, how do I push this changes to my remote repo into specific branch? I want to save all info about commit, I pulled through git cherry-pick. And, if it is possible, save the same hash of the commit like it is in side_repo.

I tried to do this:

```
git commit --allow-empty
<fix commit message>
git push -u origin develop
```

and got message

```
Branch 'develop' set up to track remote branch 'develop' from 'origin'.
Everything up-to-date
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like an xy question. Did you really want to cherry pick, or did you just want the state of arch/riscv/include/asm/pgtable.h from the second repo?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to do `git push -f origin yourLocalBranch:yourRemoteBranch`
instead of `git push -u origin develop` :)

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -b backport side_repo/master
```

Means that you are checking out `side_repo/master` into a new branch called `backport`

But then you try to push a branch called `develop`. Since you had not check out `develop` you did not modify `develop` and there are no changes to push.

The pushing is not your only problem. You are trying to cherry pick a change from your `side_repo` when you have already checked out your side repo.

```
git remote add side_repo <url_of_side_repo>   # add remote repo
git fetch side_repo master                  # fetch changes from remote repo master branch
git checkout develop                          # make sure we are modifying develop
git cherry-pick <hash_of_commit_in_side_repo> # cherry-pick the commit from side_repo/master into develop
git push -u origin develop                    # push to remote develop branch
```

Comment: Thanks, Federico! It seems, I had kind of problems with my local repo. Before I posted the question, I tried to execute the same sequence of commands you wrote, but got an error at the "git cherry-pick" step. After I cleaned my working directory and re-cloned all projected from remote repo, it worked.