# git request-pull from local branch to remote master

Tags: git, pull-request

I really love the github pull-request method for collaboration on distributed software development. It allows discussion and code review.

My goal is to use the same flow but inside our repository without github. I don't want to fork the project.

Lets imagine, I develop an awesome feature locally. And I want to make a pull request on my master branch to force code review.

```
  A---B---C feature/awesomeFeature
 /
D---E---F---G origin/master
              master
```

**is it possible to make a pull request on origin/master ?**

I tried `git request-pull feature/awesomeFeature origin` without any success

Comment: Some good details on [how the pull requests are different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6235379/465053) in Git (the software) and GitHub (the web service)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you developed your feature branch locally, you just have to use:

`git request-pull origin/master feature/awesomeFeature`

This will only give you a summary of the changes. If you want every detail, remember to add `-p` (for patch) to your command line.

Comment: It gives me error - `fatal: Not a valid revision: Viral advertising problem: C# based solution`. I had forked a Github repository. Then created a branch. Then did one commit.

Comment: How do you "merge" the pull request generated this way (= including -p)? You somehow cut it at the start of a diff and git apply that?

Comment: Why don't you have to push it first?

Answer (score 4):

Pull requests aren't actually implemented within git itself, so you will need another system to sit on top of git. If you want to host your repository yourself, you can use software such as [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) to manage your repo and allow you to make pull requests.

Comment: "pull requests" no, but "request-pull" yes! This is not the right answer, as the question was about getting the right "request-pull" command. Check my answer

Comment: I think the question was the bit in bold "is it possible to make a pull request on origin/master ?". You are right to point out that git has some pull request functionality built in, though as far as I know you can't "force code review" without some other tool.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to make a pull request on `origin/master` ?

As long as `origin/master` is a valid branch, yes.

But with Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) "`git request-pull`" learned to warn when the ref we ask them to pull from in the local repository and in the published repository are different.

See [commit 0454220](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0454220d66581f28b9688bc1b687f52cb9561798), [commit 5731dfc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5731dfce06a19f59aa1be2bd2120584864d8983b) (28 May 2019) by [Paolo Bonzini (`bonzini`)](https://github.com/bonzini).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dedc046](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dedc04642184761be54d0a861174840918e5b606), 17 Jun 2019)</sup>

> ### `request-pull`: warn if the remote object is not the same as the local one
>
> In some cases, `git request-pull` might be invoked with remote and local objects that differ even though they point to the same commit.
>   For example, the remote object might be a lightweight tag vs. an annotated tag on the local side; or the user might have reworded the tag locally and forgotten to push it.
>
> When this happens `git-request-pull` will not warn, because it only checks that "`git ls-remote`" returns an SHA1 that matches the local commit (known as `$headrev` in the script).
>
> This patch makes `git-request-pull` retrieve the tag object SHA1 while processing
>   the "`git ls-remote`" output, so that it can be matched against the local object.