# How can I create a complete offline archive of a GitHub repository?

Tags: github, archiving

We have some repos that we no longer need to keep on GitHub. If we use GitHub's archiving feature, the repos actually stay online. What we'd like instead is a way to *download an archive of all the content* (including issue reports) for a given repository, put that repository archive in a long-term preservation system, and delete the repo from GitHub. This is more than simply [backing up a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251713/backup-a-github-repository) in the sense of other similar questions on Stack Overflow, and is more like what [BackHub](https://backhub.co/faq/what-is-included-in-a-backup/) can do.  Is there a tool or set of procedures (beyond `git clone`) that will allow me to do this?

Comment: You can do it with [Repo Restore](http://www.reporestore.com). It captures all the issues, releases, etc. and lets you download it to your local machine.

Answer (score 4):

[python-github-backup](https://github.com/josegonzalez/python-github-backup) can back up a single repository in an organizational account, as well as all repositories in an account. I have tried it on individual repositories, and it worked as hoped: using its `--all` option, it captures issues, labels, milestones, pull requests, and wiki pages, as well as the repo itself.

Googling "github-backup" leads to other similar tools, but most of the others seem to have fewer features than [python-github-backup](https://github.com/josegonzalez/python-github-backup) or haven't been updated for many years.  However, I must admit I haven't explored the other options very carefully.

Tip: the essential ingredient in using Google to find a suitable tool seems to be to search for the words "github" and "backup" specifically, and not include "archive" as I was doing in my original search, or even use more elaborate search strings such as "how make backup github repository".

Answer (score 2):

If is preferable to use git clone --mirror, to get the full repo history and then

- [`git bundle --all`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309) to get only *one* file (easier to store than a collection of files)
- a long term storage system (example [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/))

Notes:

- you might want to [clone the associated GitHub wiki as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15080850/6309), if you have one.
- that won't preserve your issues/Pull Requests

Answer (score -2):

Use a folder on your local machine, google drive, or dropbox. No need to use github on non-active projects.