# git error: "fatal: not a valid revision"

Tags: git, bash, request, pull-request

I am collaborating on a repository where they upload translations of JS documentation. I translated a new file and I want to add it to such repository. The owners told me to do a pull request: that I should create a fork, create a branch, commit my translation and then make the pull request.

I've done all those things but I get the mistake "fatal: not a valid revision". I understand I must be missing the version number but since I am just uploading a new documentation, I do not know how that can be possible. This is what I have written in git bash so far to no avail:

```
git add ES6.md
```

That's my translation.

```
git commit -m "new translation"

git request-pull -p "destructuring es6" <repo URL>
```

I think I'm missing the :master at the end but I'm not sure if I should use it. This is the error message I get:

```
fatal: not a valid revision: destructuring es6
```

Comment: Most pull request items these days seem to be done through sites like GitHub that do their own special behind-the-scenes work. The `request-pull` command is quite old school; it prints out (to stdout) a string suitable for turning into email to someone. Are you sure that's what they wanted? If so, you'd want `git request-pull HEAD~1 <url>` (perhaps with `-p` added).

Comment: I asked the guys and you were right, they advised to do it through GitHub. I wanted to try it on the command line and test my git skills. Thanks, man!

Comment: Some good details on [how the pull requests are different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6235379/465053) in Git (the software) and GitHub (the web service)

Answer (score 3):

The owners from the repository asked me to do through GitHub, so I followed all those steps they told me but on GitHub.

I wanted to test my git knowledge but I didn't know people make pull requests through the website.

Comment: GitHub has an official [command line client](https://hub.github.com/), but yes, most people use the website.

Comment: I had also been trying create a pull-request since morning using command-line but it seems website is best bet :smile:.