# How to send pull request through git power shell

Tags: git, powershell, github, pull-request

we have a main `repo` name as `AppDev` and we forked it also I cloned to my local system.

Every time I am committing updated code in the following way.

`localsystem(Clone)-->forkedRepo/particularbranch`

```
git add file
git commit -m "Comment"
git push origin
```

After running the above commands, I am getting updated code into my forked repo.

Know I want to send pull request from `forkedrepo/particulareBranch` to `main(AppDev)repo/particulareBranch`.

I know,how to do this by web page.But I want to send pull request through `Git Power shell`.

can anyone suggest me with corresponding commands.

Thanks.

Comment: Not specific to GitHub but git supports native pull requests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273434/is-it-possible-to-create-merge-requests-in-pure-git-from-the-command-line/7282908

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git request-pull` which isn't Powershell specific.

The command would be, assuming your inside your forked repo:

```
git push # must push into the public repo
git request-pull origin/master forkedRepo/particularbranch
```

You would then send/email the output of that command to the original maintainer, which has all the information needed to submit your pull request.

Comment: can you explain with my names. As per I know,`origin` points to my forked repo. I am assuming I have updated code in my forked repo.after I have to send pull request to `MainRepo/particularBranch`.For that can I send in the following way.
`git request-pull origin/particularBranch mainrepo/particularBranch`.Is it right.