# Create/Update a Git pull request from command line?

Tags: git, unix, command-line, pull-request

I need to create a git pull-request from the command line, without installing any wrappers or additional software. Is there any way to do so in git? 
I can't seem to find any official git documentation which supports this.

Comment: Do you mean a GitHub pull request? Git itself doesn't really have "pull requests", only pulls.

Comment: Yes, I mean a GitHub pull-request

Comment: @Borealid: git **does** have `git request-pull`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7273434/520162

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7273434/520162

Answer (score 5):

Surprisingly (to a lot of people), pull requests are first-class citizens in the git world and not something invented by GitHub.

Use [`git request-pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull) to create an E-Mail text you could send over to someone who should fetch some revisions from a server.

This server could be something very basic like a read-only file share or whatever.

The topic is discussed in-depth in the Git Book: https://git-scm.com/book/ch5-2.html

An example: you forked a repo, introduced a patch off the `origin/master` branch and publish it on a file share called `//myserver/myrepo.git`. Then you'd type

```
git request-pull origin/master //myserver/myrepo.git
```

Then take the output of the command, paste it into an e-mail and you have your pull-request.

Answer (score 3):

#### Bash Script

Take a look at the following [article](https://tighten.co/blog/open-github-pull-request-from-terminal) which will help you to create PR from the command line.

#### Using `hub` package

- Install `hub` package on your machine. Follow this [link](https://github.com/github/hub#installation).
- Checkout to a new branch:

  ```sh
  git checkout -b your-branch-name
  ```
- Commit your changes or create an empty commit:

  ```sh
  git commit --allow-empty -m "Your commit message"
  ```
- Push the changes:

  ```sh
  git push --set-upstream origin your-branch-name
  ```
- Run the following command to create Pull Request:

  ```sh
  hub pull-request
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

It seems you want a GitHub pull request, not Git pull request.
To see the difference, this answer has a good explanation:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6235394/245966

<strike>There is no such a thing as "pull request" in Git itself. **The notion of pull requests was introduced to Git ecosystem by the platforms using Git, such as GitHub or Atlassian Stash.**</strike>

Since it's not a "native" Git concept, you don't have any Git built-ins to open a GitHub pull request from command line.

There's a https://github.com/github/hub tool that can help you automate common GitHub flows from command line.

Having said that, when it comes to opening GitHub pull request or Atlassian Stash pull request, I wrote some command line tools that you can put in `PATH` to do that job. They were written for my specific use case, feel free to modify them to your needs and use them.

For GitHub:

- get https://github.com/jakub-g/dotfiles/blob/master/github.profile#L71-83

For Atlassian Stash:

- get https://gist.github.com/jakub-g/88aca8a7cb63c731b0c6#file-open-atlassian-stash-pullrequest-sh-L9-10

For them to work, you have to have `origin` and `upstream` branches properly configured in your repos. 
They work in a crude way, by parsing the output of `git remote` commands to construct proper GitHub/Stash pull request URLs and then open them in the browser.

The shell scripts are also checking additional stuff, like making sure you open the pull request from proper branch etc.

For GitHub, also have a look at

- https://github.com/jakub-g/dotfiles/blob/master/github.profile#L117-119
- (first `npm install -g underscore`)

which can guess the number of the next pull request and put it in the commit message before you push.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7273434/520162 shows that git **does** have the concept of a pull-request...

Comment: @eckes thanks for fixing my ignorance. Was `git request-pull` added recently or it's been there forever? Honestly I never used it in last 3 years.

Comment: have a look at this post: http://vmiklos.hu/blog/using-git-request-pull.html. It's dated back to 2007, so I'd not call it a new feature :-)

Answer (score 0):

May 2020: you can use the [GitHub CLI "**gh**"](https://cli.github.com/)

See "[GitHub CLI allows you to close, reopen, and add metadata to issues and pull requests](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-05-11-github-cli-allows-you-to-close-reopen-and-add-metadata-to-issues-and-pull-requests/)"

> [GitHub CLI 0.8](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v0.8.0) makes working with pull requests and issues from your terminal even simpler. This release includes two primary features:
>
> - You no longer need to open your issue or pull request in the browser immediately after creating it just to add metadata.
>     Now you can add reviewers, labels, assignees, projects, and milestones (as applicable) when creating pull requests and issues.
> - Close and reopen pull requests and issues right from the CLI with `gh pr close`, `gh pr reopen`, `gh issue close`, and `gh issue reopen`.
>
> See how to upgrade in our [`README`](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation)!

Comment: Not available for enterprise version :|

Comment: @JohnSamuel Yes, [the `README` mentions](https://github.com/cli/cli/commit/700f86c5bce165a93aa3ecbbc850363ea8e530d8) "We are planning support for GitHub Enterprise Server after GitHub CLI is out of beta (likely toward the end of 2020)". In the context of the OP's question, github.com is enough.

Comment: Oh yeah. I read that too :). but is there an alternate way to create a pull request from command line?

Comment: @JohnSamuel There is a preliminary support in the work though: https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/823

Comment: Good to see that coming into shape :)

Comment: @JohnSamuel It will depend on your GHES version: https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/273#issuecomment-610007084

Answer (score -1):

**UPD**: It looks like it's true and you can't do it "out of the box". you'll have to install a wrapper. Check this [Can you issue pull requests from the command line on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037928/github-can-you-issue-pull-requests-from-the-command-line) maybe you can find a solution there.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @greg-449 you're right that will not solve your problem. I updated my answer