# Unable to send pull request to Github from git cli

Tags: git, github

Can , I make pull request to Github from command line ? I saw some post pointing to **git request-pull** command. But it doesn't work. To clarify, it doesn't raise any error but if I see Github UI, it doesn't show pull request. Am I missing something or there is no way ? There is a related question on this site but unable to found suitable answer.

Below is the command , I tried from cli:

**git request-pull origin/second_test https://github.com/XYZ/test123.git origin/master**

As requested, the existing thread:
[Can you issue pull requests from the command line on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037928/github-can-you-issue-pull-requests-from-the-command-line)

Comment: You mention another thread - please link to it.

Answer (score 0):

[Hub](https://hub.github.com/) is a git command-line wrapper which incorporates some GitHub specifics, including help for the pull-requests you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this wrapper https://github.com/jd/git-pull-request

I have created an alias as git pr, it will automatically try to choose from your remotes, else you can tweak in all the options manually. It also is prepared for 2FA.