# git request-pull: how to create a (github) pull request on the command line?

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface, pull-request

I've cloned a project, and pushed a branch with just a renamed readme file to README. I am trying to create a pull-request on the command line, just to try PR from here instead of a website.

```
$ git request-pull origin/master origin readme:readme
The following changes since commit 51320a3a42f82ba83cd7919d24ac4aa5c4c99ac6:

  first commit message

are available in the git repository at:

  git@github.com:example/com:example.git readme

for you to fetch changes up to 891c05c5236341bcbe33ceddc415ae921ee42e44:

  second commit message

----------------------------------------------------------------
Simone Gentili (1):
      Fix

 readme.md => README.md | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename readme.md => README.md (100%)
```

github shows no pull request and I don't see errors.

- is possibile to create a pull request directly from bash?
- is PR correct and can I view pull request list?

Comment: I don't think that this is integrated with github in any form. The command just prints a request to stdout, and you could send it to someone via email or otherwise.

Comment: you can take a look at hub: https://hub.github.com/

Comment: git, not github, has `git request-pull`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Even though they are called exactly the same thing, a GitHub pull request and a 'git request-pull' are completely different.

The git request-pull is for generating a summary of pending changes to be sent to a mailing list. It has no integration by default with GitHub.

The GitHub Pull Requests is a fully featured function of GitHub only. It allows for merging and integration of code from a different branch/fork. You can resolve merge conflicts, do code reviews, or add additional comments to a GitHub pull request.

Unfortunately the git command is named similarly to GitHub functionality which makes it sound like they should be doing the same thing.

Comment: yes this. comparing oranges to apples. i like @ChrisMaes below for the best option for doing Github PRs in the terminal.

Answer (score 23):

Github has developed [hub](https://hub.github.com/):

> hub is a command-line wrapper for git that makes you better at GitHub.

which allows you to do that using

```
hub pull-request
```

Note that, unlike `git request pull`, this **is** the same as a pull request done via the web interface.

Documentation for the `hub pull-request` command: https://hub.github.com/hub-pull-request.1.html

Comment: but `pull-request` is not part of `git`. So you can not run in it terminal. OP asks to run it on terminal, isn't it ?

Comment: @Abhisek, consider taking a look at the `hub` command first, and you will see that it lets you do exactly what is described in this answer.

Answer (score 13):

With Github's new official [CLI](https://cli.github.com/) (command line interface):

```
gh pr create --base master --title "My first cli PR" --body "What did I do?"
```

See additional [details and options](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) and [installation instructions](https://cli.github.com/manual/installation).