# GIT commands to clone/create branch to a remote machine from another remote machine

Tags: git, github

I want to clone a repo from my GIT to a remote server and through command line i want to create a branch and make changes and add this branch to the repo. I am accessing that remote server from my system
I have used following command.

```
git clone <remote address of repo> <server local address>
cd <repository>
checkout <particular branch> or
checkout -b <new branch> under master
<<<<<<<made changes>>>>>>>>>>
now what ? to make these changes available to remote repository.
```

And I have this repository available. 
Now what should be the correct sequence to create branch and make changes and add this branch to the cloned repo. and create pull request.

Comment: I an not sure I got you correctly. Do you what clone a repository between two different github servers (e.g. github service and company server) ?  I case you are asking about local repository and remote  its the standard git flow you can read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

Comment: @HaimRaman check out the edits.

Comment: sounds like the standard git flow. git add. git commit and git push?

Comment: What if instead of Push I want to send a pull request to someone

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037928/can-you-issue-pull-requests-from-the-command-line-on-github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git` relies on external standard tools (such as `ssh` or existing http servers) for network communication.

The standard way to "run actions git actions on a remote server" is simply :

- log on the remote server (e.g : using ssh)
- run the action

For example :

- To create a clone of the repo on your remote host :

  ```
  local$ ssh remote
  remote> cd /target/directory/
  remote> git clone ssh://local/repo  # <- or whatever url accessible from remote
  ```
- To checkout a given commit :

  ```
  # interactively :
  local$ ssh remote
  remote> cd /target/directory/repo && git checkout [branch]

  # batch mode :
  local$ ssh remote 'cd /target/directory/repo && git checkout [branch]'
  ```
- Pull changes :

  ```
  # interactively :
  local$ ssh remote
  remote> cd /target/directory/repo && git pull

  # batch mode :
  local$ ssh remote 'cd /target/directory/repo && git pull'
  ```
- etc ...

Comment: Yes I am accessing thoruhg ssh. I am not sure what git checkout [commit] does. "goes to the branch and commits?

Comment: @Hima Yes. To be precise: `git checkout branch/tag/commit` moves `HEAD` to the named commit (branches and tags are just labels for commits) and update files in the worktree from the tree in the commit.