# Can we create a pull request using command-line tooling?

Tags: github, command-line, pull-request

As my browser was crashing I was not able to create a pull request from GitHub UI, I was trying to create a pull request from git console but didn't found any way to create a pull request.

I have also searched for the same over the net but most of the tutorials suggested to create a pull request from UIs only. I just want to be able to handle the pull request like creation, rejection, approved and merging without the browser. Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you issue pull requests from the command line on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037928/can-you-issue-pull-requests-from-the-command-line-on-github)

Answer (score 2):

`git` and `github` are separate products.  `github` is a service that happens to use `git`, but it is not part of git, its UI is not a git interface, and git does not have any special support for github functionality.

There is a little potential confusion here, because there are "pull requests" - an integrated feature of github having to do with branch workflow - and there is `git request-pull`, a seemingly lesser-known feature of git which creates a text message you could send to another repository maintainer to request that they pull changes from your repository.

Naming confusion aside, the "pull request" you want is a feature of github, not git; and so git itself (including git console and any git UI tool) have no command for this.  You have to use a github-supplied interface, and AFAIK that means the web UI.

Answer (score 0):

To open a pull request from the command line, you can install the `hub` set of command-line tools that [GitHub supports](https://github.com/github/hub). This will allow you to create a pull request from a repository with:

```
hub pull-request
```

I'm not aware of any similar tools for managing pull requests, though.

Answer (score -1):

git add -p 
then 
git commit -m "message"

then

git push origin "your_branch"

the pull request will be created in github

Comment: sorry but it's not working, While running git add -p it's showing no changes, The second command is to commit but i don't have any staged changes then what i will be commiting ?

Comment: you should change your file and then do giit status and you will find changed files yiou want to make a pull request and your don't change any file !!

Comment: No, simple `push` doesn't automagically create a PR. You have to login to GH web interface and create a PR. And the question is — how to create a GH PR from the command line.