# How can we create pull request from command line git

Tags: git, github

How can we create pull request from command line git, and see the diffs side by side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you issue pull requests from the command line on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037928/can-you-issue-pull-requests-from-the-command-line-on-github)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+diff+side+by+side

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this has already been asked and answered (mostly)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27335800/9146188

"Git now ships with a subcommand `'git request-pull' [-p] <start> <url> [<end>]`

You can see the docs [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull)